# How to add custom addons path with odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I downloaded odoo 16 and I added the  my custom addons path  which is

```
addons_path = c:\program files\odoo 16.0.20231026\server\odoo\addons, C:\Program Files\Odoo 16.0.20231026\server\custom
```

but when I updated the app list ,  I could not find my app , I copied/pasted it and put under odoo/addons , and I found it !

Comment: You must place your custom addons inside the c:\program files\odoo 16.0.20231026\server\odoo\
_
After which your custom addon directory should be c:\program files\odoo 16.0.20231026\server\odoo\custom